# British english or American english, HTML

Tags: html, programming-languages

I was writing code and tried to align image in centre(spelled in british english)

```
align='centre'
```

above didn't work!!

There is no spelling mistake, above spelled word meaning is "middle"

when I wrote

```
align='center'
```

it worked, Does this mean HTML is written in "American English"?

EDIT after reading comments,

The thing I was worried about is, What if a developer from British background writes a renderer for web browsers such as gecko.

Does W3C or any other organisation has standard or protocol to constraint all developers to make sure they must use american english while they develop any sort of interpreter?

Comment: If it was.... What u going to do?

Comment: I can't do anything, but it is so weired

Comment: This is not the right question to ask here. Think so.

Comment: So few words are affected it's really not much of a problem. The only ones I can think of off the top of my head are "center" and "color". Being British myself, I have never even vaguely considered this to be a problem.

Comment: @Benny I know you think it's very lame question, But imagine someone writes Gecko sort of layout engine which will interpret html language and the author is having british english background. This can cause disaster.

Comment: HTML is a programming language, so we should learn the basics before do programming.

Comment: But HTML is big user friendly language. So it may consider as negative. +1 for your qn.

Comment: @SkeetOverFlow: The parameter for center/centre align could very well be spelled `foobarquurgle` for all the parser cares - it's a (well defined) sequence of characters, and it wouldn't work with an alternate sequence; case closed. The "disaster" would probably manifest as "Bug: doesn't correctly center elements when using valid attribute `align="center"`" and "Bug: incorrectly centers elements when using invalid attribute `align="centre"`". A very minor disaster IMHO.

Comment: HTML isn't programming language Benny, It's a mark-up language :)

Comment: @Benny Geo: So, do you also suggest `en-CA`, `en-AU`, and `x-lolcat` mutations of HTML to make it more user-friendly? (oh, and there **would** be much clamor for `fr-FR`, and then the Germans will demand `de-DE`, and the Swiss will want `de-CH`, and one thing leads to another, and next thing you know, the nukes are falling) ;o) But seriously: allowing attribute/tag aliases for purely aesthetical reasons is a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: +1 on your comment @Piskvor, yeah but imagine solving that bug.

Comment: @SkeetOverFlow: `Fix: corrected to American spelling to comply with the spec`. I don't care what is the motivation for the spec's language; if I'm implementing something according to the spec, I'm trying to comply with the spec, not with something I might think would perhaps be useful (remember the Browser Dark Ages?). Compatibility, y'know?

Comment: @Skeet : I'm sorry and Whatever it is .. it has some standards.

Comment: @Piskvor, No I don't know, But now I am eager to know :)

Comment: My (UK) students tend to use "colour" and "centre" when they're learning, until I tell them that CSS (and other languages) are in "American English". That's all I have to say on the topic.

Comment: Many programming languages were American so were written in American rather than English. However, since it's written only, and does not include any cultural word differences, all there is are a small handful of words that are spelt differently.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Does this mean HTML is written in "American English"?

Yes.

```
 align = left|center|right [CI]
```

However, using the `align` property is deprecated - consider using CSS's [`text-align`.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#alignment-prop)

Comment: What will happen if someone in Britain will make a web browser which will only interpret centre but not center?

Comment: @Skeet Then all of mankind's HTML will not work in that browser. It will be laughed upon by the whole world, and (somewhat incorrectly) nicknamed the "Rube Goldberg browser". Its creator, his self-esteem shattered by the global downpour of mockery, will withdraw from the browser making world and start a career as a gardener in rural Oxfordshire instead, where he will marry and have children. He will die in late 2074 of old age.

Comment: Thanks Pekka, btw does W3C or any organisation have standards which says any developer who makes gecko sort of renderer must use American english?

Comment: @Skeet well, the W3C has defined the possible values and those are in AE. But the *how* is an interesting question actually - I'm not sure whether there's a *defined* standard mandating AE in the world of HTML etc., or whether these things simply came about because the people and organizations involved in it were American. Might be a separate question worth asking on Programmers.SE maybe?

Comment: @Pekka: Nope, not standardized *(sic!)* anywhere, it just happens to be `en-US` due to historical reasons, just as the "A" in ASCII stands for "American". See also: http://www.addedbytes.com/blog/if-php-were-british/ ;)

Comment: @Piskvor, That is hilarious! I am still wondering why I got this question in middle of the night. :) thanks learnt something new at least.

Comment: @Pekka how to transfer this question to StackExchange? I couldn't find way to transfer it :(

Answer (score 6):

Don't think of the values as English words, think of them as enumerated values. The HTML standard explicitly defines certain strings that are valid.

If you don't know what the acceptable values are, you need to look them up. If you want to guess at the accepted values then you should try the American English spellings.

Comment: Yeah, it boils down to binary anyway, However I am more worried when programming languages will start getting standard of localisation ;). And I almost got this issue when my macbook start correcting my spell mistakes while I was typing and I found my english language for mac is selected to british english, which keeps converting center to centre :( and than I realised both has same meaning but dumb computer doesn't understands it :(

Comment: except for `aria-labelledby`

Answer (score 5):

I am Australian and I have to write words the wrong way just to get my code working. This quite annoying and also starts getting you into the habit of writing words the way Americans do (not good). The W3C should add in support for typing keywords like `background-colour` for the British and Australians while keeping support for keywords like `background-color` for American English. The web should be more universal.

All it takes for html and css to add support for British English this:

```
if (alignTag == "center" || alignTag == "centre")
{

...

}
```

You can find unofficial versions css made for British English such as this cool project on Github: https://github.com/HashanP/postcss-spiffing

Answer (score 1):

Using American English will solve your problem.

The issue is not the fact that the programming language does not adapt to you. It is the issue of you not adapting to the language. For example: if you go to France and speak English to someone who only knows French, it is not their fault for not understanding you. It is your fault for not speaking French.

It does not matter if you are British and the British English variant is `centre`, the computer expects `center` and if you spell it wrong it will not work. The language in this case is CSS and you have to give the computer words it can understand. The CSS engine does not understand British English. The CSS engine understands CSS.

This problem as arose because most programming languages have been created in America, thus logically most of them are in American English. As an American for example, I tend to use the British spelling of gray(grey). If I was coding in CSS and used the British spelling it would not work:

```css
/* Incorrect British English Spelling */

.greyscale {
  filter: greyscale(1);
}


/* Correct American English Spelling */

.grayscale {
  filter: grayscale(1);
}

img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th title="incorrect">Greyscale</th>
    <th title="correct">Grayscale</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1220067947798024192/30eZhfxx_400x400.png" alt="Stack Overflow (@StackOverflow) / Twitter" class="greyscale" /></td>
    <td><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1220067947798024192/30eZhfxx_400x400.png" alt="Stack Overflow (@StackOverflow) / Twitter" class="grayscale" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Unfortunately, there aren't variants of languages that support both both American and British English.